# highlight lines of code

Tags: rst2pdf

Does rst2pdf supports line highlighting in source code? Like this:

```
.. code-block:: c
   :include: example.c
   :emphasize-lines: 12,15-18
```

There is default style named `pygments-hll` that should be used but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, there isn't one. It doesn't seem trivial to do using reporlab, perhaps setting a fixed background for those lines could work.